# Symfony 3 + JWT + angular 2 + Authentication (Options Method)

Tags: php, angular, symfony, jwt

I just trying to create my sf3 api with a login using JWT but I'm having some troubles with the authentication. So here's my configurations and some test that I realised.

security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        login:
        pattern:    ^/api/auth
        stateless:  true
        anonymous:  true
        form_login:
            check_path:                 /api/auth/login-check
            success_handler:            lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:            lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session:   false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            lexik_jwt: ~
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/auth, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

routing.yml:

```
auth:
    path:       /auth
    defaults:   { _controller: api.controller.auth:postAction }
    methods:    [OPTIONS, POST]

api_login_check:
    path:       /auth/login-check
```

config.yml:

```
nelmio_cors:
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
            max_age: 3600
```

When I debug the routing I receive this output:

```
$ php bin/console debug:router
----------------------------------- ------------------ -------- ------ -----------------------------------
 Name                                Method             Scheme   Host   Path
----------------------------------- ------------------ -------- ------ -----------------------------------
....
api_homepage                        ANY                ANY      ANY    /api/
auth                                OPTIONS|POST       ANY      ANY    /api/auth
api_login_check                     ANY                ANY      ANY    /api/auth/login-check
....
```

So far so good, now here comes the problems.

I manage to test the return of the authentication with

```
$ curl -v -X POST http://api.local/api/auth/login-check -d _username=user -d _password=user
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.local (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/auth/login-check HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 33
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 33 out of 33 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.3
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=c4o6kuelf914gjnq09m38ec0c7; path=/; HttpOnly
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Date: Fri, 12 May 2017 16:37:23 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Headers
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host api.local left intact
{"token":"b2xlc9.......DW6uAwx4"}
```

Great, it's working!

When I try the same request in the browser I receive a 404 on the OPTIONS method, so I try to recreate the request with a curl OPTIONS request (really I don't know if it makes any sense, but I tried it anyway, where the response:

```
$ curl -v -X OPTIONS http://api.local/api/auth/login-check -d _username=user -d _password=user
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.local (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> OPTIONS /api/auth/login-check HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 33
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 33 out of 33 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.3
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Date: Fri, 12 May 2017 16:35:49 GMT
<
{"error":{"code":404,"message":"Not Found"}}
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host api.local left intact
```

What I understand is that the api doesn't find the route for the OPTIONS method, I even try to add *methods:    [OPTIONS, POST]* to the *api_login_check* route but same output.

Tested with and without nelmioCorsBundle, same output.

I'm a little lost here, anyone can see what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your auth routes are /oauth on routing.yml but you are using /api/auth in your examples. I think you have just little wrong configurations.

But your real problem is [preflight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), browsers do this before request, this is the cause of your authentication fails on browser and works with CURL.

Your app should response OPTIONS request for routes and tell the browser which methods or headers are permit to continue and for achieve this [NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle) is the best.

You need to cover all your routes, your configuration match only /api routes and your login, try nelmio_cors configuration like this.

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
    paths:
        '^/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['accept', 'authorization', 'content-type']
            allow_methods: ['OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
```